# Condicional em MySQL

Tags: mysql

Gostaria de obter uma string obedecendo uma condição em MySQL.
Por exemplo tenho uma tabela com uma coluna de nome `descritor` que é preenchida com `PT` ou `MT`, gostaria de obter a string `Português` para PT e `Matemática` para `MT` em uma consulta.

Exemplo:

Se descritor = `PT` então `Português`

Se descritor = `MT` então `Matemática`

Comment: me parece o caso de ter uma tabela com os nomes das disciplinas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar `CASE WHEN` para isso:

```
SELECT *,
CASE descritor  
    WHEN 'PT' THEN 'Português' 
    WHEN 'MT' THEN 'Matemática'
END AS Disciplina
FROM Tabela
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito Obrigado Ricardo Pontual